# How to design a custom view

Tags: android, view

I'm not sure how to define the specific View I need here, therefore my question title is quite general.

I developing a game, and I'm looking for a way to design and maintain the storage of the player.

an empty storage would look like this:
[image: empty storage]

and then I need to be able to add an item according to starting position (like in two dimensional array), width and height, while width and height are the number of cells.

so after receiving a command: addItem(item=Axe, position=1, width=2, height=2)

I'll get this;
[image]

note: the background of the item image would be the same background underneath the cells.

I need a way that can be supported by different screens

Comment: You've asked a really really broad question. What have you tried so far? Is there anything you can tell us to help narrow down the question you're asking?

Comment: @Kurtis Nusbaum: I really can't figure out a way to approach this. I thought about TableLayout, GridView, or just draw everything using canvas

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing a game you shouldn't use standard UI elements. You should rather take a look at how to render with OpenGL on Android. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) you can find a short introduction about using OpenGL on Android.

Comment: A 2D game doesn't require OpenGL.

Comment: You should watch the video of game development under Android (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic).

Comment: You should at least use the Canvas if you develop a 2D game.

Comment: I use it. but for the storage display I'm not sure that this is the way. and I watched the video already, my game doesn't require openGl